# cannot set the MediaRecorder profile using setProfile() it returns a null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

whenever I try to set the profile of my MediaRecorder object to camcorderProfile it gives me a NullPointerException which means that my camcorderProfile is somehow null but I have set it. Here is my entire function that prepares the recorder and camera for running.

```
  private void prepareRecorder()
  {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
    camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P);

    if (usecamera)
    {
        camera.unlock();
        recorder.setCamera(camera);
    }
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);

   String fileName = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    if(camcorderProfile.fileFormat == MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
    {
        fileExtension = ".3gp";
    }

    if(camcorderProfile.fileFormat == MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
    {
        fileExtension = ".mp4";
    }


    try
    {
        FileBuffer = File.createTempFile(fileName, fileExtension, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        recorder.setOutputFile(FileBuffer.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    recorder.setMaxDuration(30000); // 30 seconds

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CamcorderProfile` can be null if the requested quality is not supported by camera. In your case its back camera since you are not passing camera ID while querying for profile.

So its better to check for the support using API:

`public static boolean hasProfile (int quality)`

Comment: thanks so much! I just passed the setprofile() my cameraInfo.facing and set the quality to high. I should probably read more of the api next time.